# How to obtain sensitivity when applying cross validation?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret, confusion-matrix

Let's consider data

```
set.seed(20)     
y <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
x <- data.frame(rnorm(100), rexp(100))
```

I want to perform cross validation and output sensitivity and specificity. I found out that I can provide additional input to train function 'metric' to specify which metric I want to have. SO :

```
# train the model on training set

library(caret)
cross <- train(as.factor(y) ~ .,
  data = cbind(y,x),
  metric = 'Sensitivity',
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
,
  method = "glm",
  family = binomial()
)
```

However I see the problem :

```
The metric "Sensitivity" was not in the result set. Accuracy will be used instead.
```

Is there any solution how Sensitivity and specificity can be used in cross validation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimising caret for sensitivity still seems to optimise for ROC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265400/optimising-caret-for-sensitivity-still-seems-to-optimise-for-roc)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `caret`, you can find some of the answer in the documentation of this package. It states that the `metric` parameter is ...

> a string that specifies what summary metric will be used to select the
> optimal model. By default, possible values are "RMSE" and "Rsquared"
> for regression and "Accuracy" and "Kappa" for classification. If
> custom performance metrics are used (via the summaryFunction argument
> in trainControl, the value of metric should match one of the
> arguments. If it does not, a warning is issued and the first metric
> given by the summaryFunction is used. (NOTE: If given, this argument
> must be named.)

So by default, a 'Sensitivity' metric does not exist. But you can define such a metric yourself. One approach is to use the `trainControl` function to pass a custom function that calculates sensitivity. See [Optimising caret for sensitivity still seems to optimise for ROC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265400) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset `confusionMatrix()` with `$` or `[]` and this will probably give you what you need.

You can also use function like `negPredValue()` to get Sensitivity and Specificity.

The 'Sensitivity' metric does not exist for `train()` in caret package.

Comment: Yes - the $ solution would be correct, if confusionMatrix will be output of crossvalidation.

Comment: I don't quite understand solutionwith negPredValue, because the only output we get from cross validation is Accuracy and Kappa